# Laravel вывод данных из таблицы по столбцу текущей таблицы

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, проектирование

Есть таблица Payments (платежи), структура такая
'id','id_client', 'title', 'payment_type'
Как видно она имеет в себе свойство id_client, соответственно id конкретного клиента из таблицы клиентов, чтобы видеть какому клиенту принадлежит платеж и они связаны через hasMany.
Необходимо вывести из таблицы Payments все данные, то есть 'id','title', 'payment_type' у которых id_client равен тому, что поступает из url. То есть нужно обратиться к свойствам самой модели.
А затем, вместо цифры в 'payment_type' вывести название из связанной таблицы payment_types
Так выглядит
**Роут:**

```
Route::get('client/{client}/payments', 'ApiController@getPaym')->name('api-get-payments');
```

**Контроллер:**
Тут применяю после where метод first, так как с get() выходит ошибка что метод getPayments не существует
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getPayments does not exist.
Но first() выводит только первую попавшуюся запись, а мне нужны все платежи клиента, то есть все записи где id_client равен определённому числу.
Как можно вывести все записи,а не только первую?

```
public function getPaym($id_client) {
        $match = Payments::where('id_client', $id_client)->first();
        $user = $match->getPayments();
        return view('admin_payment_page', compact('user','match'));
    }
```

**Метод в модели Payments для связи с типом платежа**

```
public function getPayments(){
        return $this->hasOne('App\Model\Payments_types', 'id', 'payment_type')->get();
        }
```

**Вывод во view**

```
@foreach($user as $el)
    <a href="{{ route('api-get-payments', ['client' => $match->id_client]) }}"></a>
    <tr>     
            <td>{{ $el->name }}</td>
     </tr>
@endforeach
```

Соответственно вопросы:

1. Как вывести все записи с определённым id_client из таблицы Payments,а не только первую попавшуюся?
2. А потом вывести вместо цифры из поля 'payment_type' название из связанной таблицы payments_types?
   Подскажите кто знает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решение Вашей проблемы заменить `first` на `get`.**

> выходит ошибка что метод getPayments не существует Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::getPayments does not exist.

Выводит всё правильно. Просто проблема в том, что php не строго типизированный язык, в результате все попросту не отслеживают какой тип данных возвращает тот или иной метод.
Если обратить внимание на текст ошибки, вы пытаетесь вызвать метод `getPayments` из класс `Collection`. Но откуда он там? он же определён в Вашей модели! (надеюсь поняли в чём проблема)

**Решение**
В `$match` у вас КОЛЛЕКЦИЯ МОДЕЛЕЙ, а не просто МОДЕЛЬ
По суть коллекция тот же массив который можно перебрать либо через цикл либо через встроенные методы.
Вам надо написать цикл `foreach` и у каждого элемента коллекции (то есть модели) вызвать метод `->getPayments()`, но это не корректный способ так как будет много запросов sql.

Для решения подобных задач есть метод `load()` и метод `with()` можете почитать о них в документации.

Приведу пример с `with`:

```
$match = Payments::where('id_client', $id_client)->with('getPayments')->get();
```

В результате во время перебора `match` а не `user`. Уже на фронте внутри будут у каждого элемента значения возвращаемые `getPayments`
и переменная `$user` уже не нужна. Так как она не будет работать.

**UPD**

```
@foreach($match as $el)
    <a href="{{ route('api-get-payments', ['client' => $el->id_client])}}"></a>
    ...
@endforeach
```

Comment: Я понимаю, что метод getPayments определён в модели, но почему при замене first() на get() происходит вызов метода из Collection, а не из моей модели? Поясните пожалуйста этот момент.

Comment: @Andrey потому что метод get возвращает массив элементов, а first первый найденный. вы же не можете из массива вызвать метод какой-то, у него же нет их

Comment: Понял, сделал как Вы предлагали. Но теперь натыкаюсь на ошибку Property [id_client] does not exist on this collection instance. Во view перебираю как Вы и писали $match, но вызываю свойство  id_client таблицы Payments, по которому и нужно делать выборку, тоже из $match, это не правильно ведь? Необходимо вызывать из как то по другому же? Иначе получается что пытаюсь это свойство вызвать из массива же. Вызов во view: <a href="{{ route('api-get-payments', ['client' => $match->id_client]) }}"></a>

Comment: @Andrey дополнил ответ. Еще раз говорю не юзера перебирать. И переменная $match это МАССИВ у массива нет свойств для получения таким образом. Вы должны его перебрать и у каждого элемента взять нужное свойство

Comment: Спасибо большое Вам!!